# Create `has_($value)`column for table values

Tags: postgresql

I would like to perform an operation similar to a dynamic pivot table. I utilize Postgresql as database framework. The table `t` has a column with values 10, 20, and 30. I wish to create n columns, in this case equal to 3, to allow the boolean assignment `has_($value)` equal to 1 if existent in respective group, or 0 if not. I tried to understand `tablefunc` and `crosstab` without success.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (
   id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
   value INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO t (id, value) VALUES
(1, 10),
(1, 20),
(2, 10),
(3, 30),
(3, 20)
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the expected output based on your sample data

Comment: If you are looking for a solution that dynamically returns a different number of columns depending on the data in the table, then this won't work. The number, names and types of the columns of a query must be known to the database before it actually starts running the query.

Comment: In case I cast all to text, is it possible?

Comment: No casting to varchar will not help. The DBMS needs to know both **number of columns** and data type or each before it begins processing the query. To get dynamic result set you will have to construct the query in code before submitting to the sql engine.  And if you do so be watchful for [sql injection](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/web-security-zone/sql-injection-cheat-sheet-for-developers/). Just for starters.